# Show that $j': E' \rightarrow M'$ is a quotient function and $\ker j' = M^o$

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Problem:** Let $E$ is a Banach space, consider a closed subspace $M$ of $E$ and $j: M \rightarrow E$ is a embedding function. Show that
>   $j': E' \rightarrow M'$ is a quotient function and $\ker j' = M^o$, in
>   which $E'$ and $M'$ are dual spaces of $E$ and $M$ respectively, $M^o$
>   the polar of $M$.

Can you give me some hint to solve the problem.

Comment: every injection is a monic!

Comment: Could you give me definiton of "monic"?

Comment: sorry, you do not need monic, here, you only need it for the exactness in the middle of the dualizing functor. but i am just typing the answer

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to prove that $j'$ is surjective, hence consider $f \in M^*$, i.e. a map $f:M\to k$, now we want to find a morphism $g: E \to k$ such that $j'(g)=f$,but this is equivalent to $g|_M=f$. So take a linear complement $V$ of $M$ in $E$ (this exists by basis completion). So an $x \in E\cong M \oplus V$ may be written uniquely as $m_x + v_x$  and so we may define $g: E \to k$ by $g(x):= f(m_x)$.
now this clearly restricts to $f$ on $M$.

Furthermore, since all elements by definition in $M^o$ send vectors in $M$ to zero, they are clearly the kernel of $j'$, as they restrict to zero on $M$ (as this property is precisely the defining property of $M^o$).

Comment: Do you means $M^*$ be the dual space of $M$?

Comment: exactly, that is by the way the standard notation, also be aware that i just changed the answer, since one can't use the polar thingy as a subspace of the space itself (the reasoning for kernel however still holds), but any linear complement still does the job

Comment: I'm using book named "Introduction to Functional Analysis - Reinhold Meise and Dietmar Vogt". It use the notation $M'$. But I think there is no difference.

Comment: the dual stays the dual! just different notations, but that can happen.

Comment: What is $``k''$ here?

Comment: the ground field, for you most likely $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as you are working with a banach space. However, we never needed that. This is only dependent on the vector space structure.